# Bootstrap 4 responsive tables won't take up 100% width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am building a web app using Bootstrap 4 and running into some weird issues.  I want to utilize Bootstrap's table-responsive class to allow horizontal scrolling of the tables on mobile devices.   On desktop devices the table should take up 100% of the containing DIV's width.

As soon as I apply the .table-responsive class to my table, the table shrinks horizontally and no longer takes up 100% of the width.   Any ideas?

Here is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="mdl-js">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="application-name" content="">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bundle.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-responsive" id="Queue">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><span span="sr-only">Priority</span></th>
                            <th>Origin</th>
                            <th>Destination</th>
                            <th>Mode</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th><span span="sr-only">Action</span></th>
                         </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr class="trip-container" id="row-6681470c-91ce-eb96-c9be-8e89ca941e9d" data-id="6681470c-91ce-eb96-c9be-8e89ca941e9d">
                              <td>0</td>
                              <td>PHOENIX, AZ</td>
                              <td>SAN DIEGO, CA</td>
                              <td>DRIVING</td>
                              <td><time datetime="2017-01-15T13:59">2017-01-15 13:59:00</time></td>
                              <td><span class="trip-status-toggle fa fa-stop" data-id="6681470c-91ce-eb96-c9be-8e89ca941e9d" data-trip-status="1"></span></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="steps-container" data-steps-for="6681470c-91ce-eb96-c9be-8e89ca941e9d" style="display: none;">
                              <td colspan="6" class="no-padding"></td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
           </div>
           <br>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bundle.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

If I apply a 100% width to the .table-responsive class, it makes the table itself a 100% wide but the child elements (TBODY, TR, etc.) are still narrow.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The following WON'T WORK. It causes another issue. It will now do the 100% width but it won't be responsive on smaller devices:

```
.table-responsive {
    display: table;
}
```

All these answers introduced another problem by recommending `display: table;`. The only solution as of right now is to use it as a wrapper:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
...
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Fidgeted with this for forever- too early to think about simply wrapping it.  Your the man

Comment: Using the `table-responsive` class as a wrapper harkens back to Bootstrap 3...? Glad there is a solution for now! Bootstrap 4 _Alpha_ ;-)

Comment: Not seeing this work with beta.  Looks like you will need to remove the div and add "table-responsive" along "table" .  Like so.. <table class="table table-responsive">

Comment: this issue still hasn't been resolved in bootstrap 4, although one part of agrees with your answer, the migration instructions from bootstrap 3 to 4 state: "responsive tables no longer require a wrapping element. Instead, just put the .table-responsive right on the <table>."... found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#tables

Comment: Works perfectly for me on version 4.3.1! Thank you

Comment: With the responsive container and a bordered table, the top border seems to get cut off... solutions to that?

Answer (score 58):

This solution worked for me:

just add another class into your table element:
`w-100 d-block d-md-table`

so it would be :
`<table class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">`

for bootstrap 4 `w-100` set the width to 100% `d-block` (display: block) and `d-md-table` (display: table on min-width: 576px)

[Bootstrap 4 display docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: Works for Bootstrap4 Beta!  The key was w-100.  thank you.

Comment: Does this solution not have the same effect as just doing `<table class="table table-responsive-md">` ?

Answer (score 25):

If you're using V4.1, and according to their docs, don't assign .table-responsive directly to the table. The table should be .table and if you want it to be horizontally scrollable (responsive) add it inside a .table-responsive container (a `<div>`, for instance).

> Responsive tables allow tables to be scrolled horizontally with ease. Make any table responsive across all viewports by **wrapping a .table with .table-responsive.**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
  ...
  </table>
</div>
```

doing that, no extra css is needed.

In the OP's code, .table-responsive can be used alongside with the .col-md-12 on the outside .

Comment: This is supposed to be the right answer since the stable version of bootstrap. Thx

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 8):

None of these answers are working (date today 9th Dec 2018). The correct resolution here is to add .table-responsive-sm to your table:

```
<table class='table table-responsive-sm'>
[Your table]
</table>
```

This applies the responsiveness aspect only to the SM view (mobile). So in mobile view you get the scrolling as desired and in larger views the table is not responsive and thus displayed full width, as desired.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#breakpoint-specific

Comment: I found the same thing -- that applying the `table-responsive-?` class directly to the `table` element was the only way to get it to work as described, rather than using a wrapper `div` -- but the code in your example actually means that only `xs` viewports will have the responsive behavior and `sm` and larger will be 'normal'.

Answer (score 7):

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table with
>   .table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}, making the table scroll
>   horizontally at each max-width breakpoint of up to (but not including)
>   576px, 768px, 992px, and 1120px, respectively.

just wrap table with .table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}

for example

```
<div class="table-responsive-md">
    <table class="table">
    </table>
</div>
```

[bootstrap 4 tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/)

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the responsive table in particular doesn't behave as it should. You can patch it by getting rid of `display:block;`

```
.table-responsive {
    display: table;
}
```

I may file a bug report.

**Edit:**

[It is an existing bug.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21577)

Answer (score 3):

The solution compliant with the v4 of the framework is to set the proper breakpoint. Rather than using .table-responsive, you should be able to use .table-responsive-sm (to be just responsive on small devices)

You can use any of the available endpoints: **table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}**

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `.table-responsive` class adds the property **`display: block`** to your element which changes it from the previous **`display: table`**.

Override this property back to **`display: table`** in your own stylesheet

```
.table-responsive {
    display: table;
}
```

***Note: make sure this style executes after your bootstrap code for it to override.***

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the `table-responsive` class giving the table a property of `display:block`, which is strange because this overwrites the `table` classes original `display:table` and is why the table shrinks when you add `table-responsive`.

Most likely its down to bootstrap 4 still being in dev. You are safe to overwrite this property with your own class that sets `display:table` and it won't effect the responsiveness of the table.

e.g.

```
.table-responsive-fix{
   display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking in consideration the other answers I would do something like this, thanks!

```
.table-responsive {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        display: table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that using the recommended table-responsive class in a wrapper still causes responsive tables to (surprisingly) shrink horizontally:

```
<div class="table-responsive-lg">
    <table class="table">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

The solution for me was to create the following media breakpoints and classes to prevent it:

```
.table-xs {
    width:544px;
}

.table-sm {
    width: 576px;
}

.table-md {
    width: 768px;
}

.table-lg {
    width: 992px;
}

.table-xl {
    width: 1200px;
}

/* Small devices (landscape phones, 544px and up) */
@media (min-width: 576px) {  
    .table-sm {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) The navbar toggle appears at this breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .table-sm {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-md {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .table-sm {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-md {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-lg {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .table-sm {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-md {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-lg {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-xl {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Then I can add the appropriate class to my table element. For example:

```
<div class="table-responsive-lg">
    <table class="table table-lg">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Here the wrapper sets the width to 100% for large and greater per Bootstrap. With the table-lg class applied to the table element, the table width is set also set to 100% for large and greater, but set to 992px for medium and smaller. The classes table-xs, table-sm, table-md, and table-xl work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if helps, but wrap your table responsive in a div and add .responsive-table class to both:

```
table.table-responsive{
        display: block;
        overflow: scroll;
    }


.table-responsive {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

This gives a 100% expanded surrounding div which scales with the column width, whilst then making the actual table scrollable. The solutions above wouldn't work if I had a side column on the page, as they assume 100% width.

Comment: This answer works!

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4.x use display utilities:

`w-100 d-print-block d-print-table`

**Usage**:

```
<table class="table w-100 d-print-block d-print-table">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the "sr-only" element and its styles inside of the table are what's causing this bug. At least I had the same issue and after months of banging our head against the wall that's what we determined the cause was, though I still don't understand why. Adding `left:0` to the "sr-only" styles fixed it.