# Bootstrap 4 .table-responsive class won't take 100% width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I got 2 tables with same HTML and both declared as:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-responsive">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Item 01</th>
                      <th>Item 02</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Item 01</td>
                      <td>Item 02</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I got on my screen:

[image: Check this picture]

The second and consecutive tables declared with the same HTML don't get 100% width on `thead` and `tbody`...
What is wrong here?

UPDATE:

My first table was working because of the content of the last line, it was long enough to make it fit 100% on my card div.

Actually  [it's a issue on Bootstrap 4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21577), so the -2 reputation on this question are invalid. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: You will need to post more code so we can see what other things could be affecting the table.

Comment: Sup guys, just got back from lunch (and already got -2 on my question).

Example that is not working for me:
https://www.bootply.com/yQCAW8tiN0

There on bootply it works fine, but on my app it looks like this:
http://prntscr.com/h7duxs

Exatcly same code, I am gonna research more, got this question on stackoverflow about the same subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747667/bootstrap-4-responsive-tables-wont-take-up-100-width
 
Also @Pete you don't need to answer like that, it may cause people to be afraid of asking, and asking is the main objective of this website.

Comment: Could you please point where is the unacceptance of my question @Pete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out that it's a issue on Bootstrap V4, you can see in this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21577), and my first table is not working, it's just the content of the last line that is long enough to fullfil the table width, so it looks like it works.

EDIT: It got fixed by adding the class *table-responsive* as a parent div of the *table*, [here is the ship list for the fix](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23278) and [the issue that reported the bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21577).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item 01</th>
                        <th>Item 02</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Item 01</td>
                        <td>Item 02</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, you're right, I corrected it with the HTML snippet, you just need to be more polite with people ;) Thanks

Comment: @Pete, can you take a look at my question? It's been a year but I got revisited here because of positive votes.