# Why won't bootstrap's `table-fixed` make my table into a scrolling one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a table that has about 550 rows that I would like to be scrollable. I am using the `table-fixed` style for bootstrap, but it doesn't seem to be working. It also doesn't seem to register `table-condensed`. I'm not sure what's going on - I've checked several examples and mine looks just like them. Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

I took the data out of the examples because it's a ton, but if you think you need it to answer what's going on, I can provide it. Thanks.

```
  <div class="container pt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 col md-5">
        <h1>Data</h1>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>The following table includes all of the data used for plotting during this project</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="table-responsive-md">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-fixed">
          <thead>
              ...
          </thead>
          <tbody>
               ...
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747667/bootstrap-4-responsive-tables-wont-take-up-100-width

Comment: `table-fixed` or `header-fixed`? the code you shared is scrollable as it is...

Comment: `table-fixed` - this code should be scrollable, but it's not - it extends the length of the page to basically be the length of the table rows. my understanding was `table-fixed` will create a fixed size table that prevents exactly this. but my code above doesn't seem to work. does there need to be content below the table for that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, comment... you need:

- a table of fixed height (not equal to the height of the page)
- the table should be scrollable

for this, you need to place this `table-fixed` class on the div which has the table as the child; and for this class, the properties to be: `height:300px; overflow:scroll;`

working **snippet** below:

```css
.table-fixed {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container pt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 col md-5">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive-md table-fixed">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply....thank you! this is what i was missing...specifically my table being a fixed height